# need assistance identifying formula and help proving it

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, proof-writing

This is the identity:

$$
\int_{x=0}^\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x^8}dx = \int_{x=0}^\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} { \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{k-1+8i}}dx = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2} ^ k} \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{16^i\left(8i+k\right)}
$$

Can anyone prove this?

Also, can anyone identify it, i.e. provide additional information, context, name it if possible, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a^{i}=\frac{1}{1-a}$ provided $\lvert a\rvert<1$. Applying this to $x^{8}$ we have:

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{8i}=\frac{1}{1-x^{8}}$

Notice that this is valid since $0<x<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ so $0<x^{8}<\frac{1}{16}$.

The final equality comes from switching the sum and the integral which follows from uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: the geometric series is for $|x|<1$ $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{i}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$